# Taking a screenshot of a view that is currently not on screen on iOS

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiimage

I'm trying to make a transition between two ViewControllers.  My Transition class has a property for the destination view controller.  When I try to get a screenshot of the destination's view, I use this method:

```
+ (UIImage *)renderImageFromView:(UIView *)view withRect:(CGRect)frame {
    // Create a new context the size of the frame
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(frame.size, YES, 0);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // Render the view 
    [view.layer renderInContext:context];

    // Get the image from the context
    UIImage *renderedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    // Cleanup the context you created
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return renderedImage;
}
```

So when I want the image, I'll do this:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage renderImageFromView:destinationController.view withRect:destinationController.view.bounds];
```

I tried it on a blank UIViewController with an orange background color and a label.  I get the orange background color, but I do not get the label that was created in IB.  Is there a way to get a proper screenshot of the new view I plan on showing?  Thanks!

Comment: Your method requires that you pass a view and a frame but you are only passing a view.  Are you showing two separate functions?

Comment: @Kris Gellci You are right, I copied and pasted the wrong usage.  Will fix it.

Comment: I see you're having the same problem -- I was working on your other question about the iBooks animation when I tried the same thing you're trying here.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure the view's layer is drawn to first. Calling renderInContext on a `CALayer` will only recursively call additional child `CALayer`s. You need your child `UIView`s to draw themselves, not just using the `CALayer`.

Try calling

```
[view drawrect:frame];
```

instead of

```
[view.layer renderInContext:context];
```

As long as you have an open graphics context(which you do at that point), `drawrect` should draw directly into that.

Comment: So is it ok to call drawRect in this case?  I just remember reading about using setNeedsDisplay instead of calling drawRect directly?  thanks!

Comment: You are correct, normally you don't want to call it directly because the system will call it as needed, and can optimize the number of calls it makes. In this case, you are in a graphics context and need to draw, so I think it's fine, as long as you don't call it more than you need to(hopefully once), and make sure to do it on the main thread. In any other situation, you normally just want the system to do the drawing without having to manage any context. If you do a setNeedsDisplay, then the drawing will not happen on your graphics context that you just created.

Comment: Do you know why I'd be getting a blank screen with `[view drawRect:frame]`?  I don't seem to be seeing anything drawn to the context.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is if the frame is not correct, or the view is empty.