# Getting a screenshot of a ViewController's view without showing it

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, xamarin.ios

I need to get a screenshot of a ViewController's view without showing the view controller on screen.

Essentially the situation is this: I have three view controllers: VC1, VC2, and VC3. VC3 needs to receive a screenshot of VC2's view.

There are 2 different ways to navigate to VC3:

1. Hitting a "done" button on the navigation bar of VC2. This takes a screenshot of VC2 and passes it to VC3
2. Tapping a row in a table in VC1 takes you directly to VC3. Somehow need to send a screenshot of VC2 to VC3.

How can I get a screen shot from VC1 to VC3 without ever showing VC2?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13979067/taking-a-screenshot-of-a-view-that-is-currently-not-on-screen-on-ios, you will have to translate to C#

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! However, with this method, the result is the same as what the OP got which is a completely clear image.
I have decided to just go the long and painful route of drawing the view exactly as it appears using Core Graphics and Core Text.